# In django-forms, how can I make the values of 'name' column of foreign database visible in the selection choices

Tags: django, django-forms

My Django site has a database model named `Status` with:

```
 class Status(models.Model):
     x = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True)
```

The `Person` database model referenced here contains attributes such as `name`, `profile_pic` etc.

In `forms.py`, I have:

```
class StatusForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StatusForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
            model = Status
            fields = ['x']
```

Now, when running the site, I get:

[image]

I want the `name` attribute of the `Person` to be shown in the choices instead of being shown Person object(1), Person object (2).....

How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [**Other model instance methods[Django-doc]**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#other-model-instance-methods)

> Most notably, to display an object in the Django admin site and as the value inserted into a template when it displays an object

In your `Person` model use [****str**()[Django-doc]**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#str) as

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.charField(max_length=100)
    .....

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Person` model just add the `str` method as following:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    # Your fields here
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

That will return the name for every instance in the choicefield.